# How to correctly setup the cron jobs for sending of the Order Confirmation Emails?

Tags: cron

I´m trying to fix the issue with Order Confirmation Emails being delayed by 20 minutes or so...I asked the hosting company to set up the cron jobs correctly and they replied this:

---

If the Magento shopping cart is using some kind of script that is run by cron job, you would have to provide more information so that we could set up the server accordingly. Please note that scripting issues are out of our scope of support. If you can provide us with the additional information on the name of the script and what cron job is used to run it, we will gladly make the changes for you.

Did you try searching for the plugins for the Magento that could do that kind of service? As I said before, I am unable to locate the right cron job that is running this action, and without the exact cron job, we aren't able to do anything regarding this delay.

Can you clarify do the confirmation emails go one by one, as any customer places the order, or are they accumulated and sent in larger number all at once?

### Any additional information would be very useful in further troubleshooting.

When I went to the cPanel - Advanced - Cron Jobs - I saw 2 cron jobs setup in there. Do I need to modify one of these cron jobs?

1. Minute --) 12,18,38,48   php /home/ACCOUNTid/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null
2. Minute --) 03 Hour --) 22 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/cli.php --backup --auto=1 --insid=67_58956

I also found this:

---

using cPanel - you can set up your cron in Advanced section -> Cron Jobs

In the Common Settings field, select once every five minutes in the drop-down.

In Command, put the following action (if your Magento root is public_html)

/bin/sh /home/ACCOUNTid/public_html/cron.sh

### Add that cron job and your cron should be up and running.

So I did that. Is this correct you think? Where do I configure these Cron jobs for sending Order Confirmation Emails in the Admin panel of the Magento shopping cart? And what are the correct settings for that?

Comment: If your hosting company is resistant to this kind of support, I suggest you find a new host that is happy to provide some Magento specific support. There are loads of great hosts that don't need me to plug them.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: **always use cron.sh, not cron.php**. The .sh version has protection against multiple invocations. In theory, cron jobs created by extensions should prevent this themselves, but reality is different and can cause corruption of data, high server load or jobs hanging indefinitely so other jobs can't run.

Your current cronjob is setup a bit weird:

- 12,18 => 6 minutes
- 18,38 => 20 minutes
- 38,48 => 10 minutes
- 48-12 => 24 minutes

So yes, that explains the delays. Use `*/5` or `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55` if CPanel throws an error on the expression.